# Problem connecting to mongodb atlas using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a problem connecting to Mongo.
Would appreciate help..
Thanks

```
client =MongoClient("mongodb+srv://srdht:srdht@srddataset.2htbr.mongodb.net/dbImages?retryWrites=true&w=majority",ssl=True,ssl_cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
    db=client.get_database('dbImages')
    records = db.atopic
    records.count_documents({})
    new_student = {
        'name': 'ram',
        'roll_no': 321,
        'branch': 'it'
    }
    records.insert_one(new_student)
    new_students = [
        {
            'name': 'alex',
            'roll_no': 320,
            'branch': 'it'
        },
        {
            'name': 'john',
            'roll_no': 30,
            'branch': 'ece'
        }
    ]
    
    records.insert_many(new_students)
```

and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/student/Documents/GitHub/SRD/imageProcessing.py", line 24, in <module>
    **client =MongoClient("mongodb+srv://srdht:srdht@srddataset.2htbr.mongodb.net/dbImages?retryWrites=true&w=majority",ssl=True,ssl_cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')**
  File "C:\Users\student\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 672, in __init__
    connect_timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\student\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 453, in parse_uri
    **'%s -m pip install "pymongo[srv]"' % (python_path))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs. To fix this error install pymongo with the srv extra:
 C:\Users\student\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe -m pip install "pymongo[srv]"**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dnspython, try this command to install it:

```
python -m pip install pymongo[srv]
```

Comment: I tried. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall but still the problem remained

Comment: I think you are using a very old version of python(2.7). Can you check the running version with: "python --version"

You must install the package on the correct version of python:
C:\Users\student\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe -m pip install "pymongo[srv]"

Comment: I'm working on interapter 3.7 and still have the same error

Comment: Try to install the package on the 3.7: python3 -m pip install pymongo[srv]